# Is there a way to exclude fields during select in MikroORM?

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, mikro-orm

I want to select some 100 fields in a nested populate query in MikroORM with MySQL and just want to leave out some 20 fields. Leaving 20 makes more sense to me, instead of selecting 100, something like `db.find().select("-password")` in MongoDB. The documentation seems to have only documented Partial Fetches where I can select fields not unselect them.

Comment: There's no way of doing this in SQL or any ORM I have ever used, so while my knowledge of mikro-orm is non-existent, I'd be astonished if there was a way of doing this. I also don't think this makes more sense - yes, it reduces the one time effort of writing the code (20 columns vs 80), however in every other aspect it is worse (IMO).

Comment: Listing what not to select would require querying the meta data to find out what to select, making the process less efficient. It would also be much harder to read/debug the code for the same reason, it requires knowing all the columns first to work out what is left after the exclusions. You can generate the list of columns using something like `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('')`, then add this to your code, but as I say, I think it would be easier to read/maintain to include what you are selecting rather than what you are not

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for your Input. I think MikroORM already has the meta data, because we define entities. And with Typescript it even validates if the column I am selecting is actually in then table, before I even run the code. Rather than a SQL approach to my question I am looking more towards extending the ORM's capability to unselect a few columns since it already has the list and generates the query at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since v6.0.0 you can use `exclude` option, which will omit the provided properties and select everything else.

```
const authorWithoutEmail = await em.findOne(Author, '...', {
  exclude: ['email']
});
```

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-manager#partial-loading

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation there is a feature for hidden fields which you can use to make the field you do not want **hidden**.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/serializing#hidden-properties

Comment: Not what I was looking for. I already use hidden props. I want to do a negative select. If I want 45/50 properties, I want to suppy only the 5 I don't want to select.